# Mac is stuck in some kind of automatic layout windowing mode

Tags: mac, window-manager

My mac has suddenly stopped letting me freely move around my application windows around the screen, and its just allowing them to be shown in a grid view. If i try resizing windows, they just get automatically resized back. I've tried searching for some kind of setting in accessability, but i have not found out how to turn this off, its driving me mad.

Attached are screenshots of how it forces the layout of windows present

[image]

It is not possible to resize any of the windows here, and there is always a blue rectangle around the window with focus

[image]

with 2 windows showing, they are forced into this layout

Comment: Never saw this though, but  If you can access launchpad, see if any app is doing so.. There are window splitter apps available. I would be surprised if it is natively possible.

Comment: Did you install any new application or tool recently?

Comment: no i have not installed anything recently, it seems really similar to any split window auto layout apps yes. I've looked through task manager to see if any are running, and it does not seem like it. I've also removed every app from login items, and restarted

Comment: have you checked whether any key has been pressed from your keyboard? Just try to clean the keyboard and see as blue rectangle goes or not.

Comment: yes i tried checkin on screen keyboard if any keys were pressed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly your computer has a window manager installed on it.

That one in particular might be chunkwm (the blue border around your selected window reminds me of my time using chunkwm, but I assume all window managers provide some feature like that). chunkwm is also very popular, so maybe it's what's ended up installed on your computer.

Try stopping it, maybe one of these commands will work:

```
brew services stop chunkwm
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.koekeishiya.chunkwm.plist
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.chunkwm.plist
```

if none are found try searching for it

```
launchctl dumpstate | grep chunkwm
```

if `chunkwm` still isn't found, then the window manager you have isn't chunkwm.

Just look up a list of window managers online and search for each one in turn on your computer. **Edit** a good starting point would be yabai, the successor to chunkwm.

It might also be possible to hunt through

```
launchctl dumpstate | grep '=> true'
```

for it.

Comment: Now I am wondering how OP got it without their knowledge. Is it available by default?

Comment: @ankii no, you have to install it yourself. In fact, iirc, it requires quite a lot of steps to install and set up.

Comment: maybe something i installed along time ago, and something just activated it?

Comment: I actually fixed the problem now with checking "Displays have separate spaces" in Mission Control. Seems like a bug that that fixed it though, and i think your solution might also have worked. I think i had installed that plugin long time ago, but have no idea why it suddenly was activated now, since i basically never used it

Comment: @bogen there's no functionality in macOS that provides this. Your window manager might be configured to only turn itself on when "Displays have separate spaces" is false. Read up on all the options in the chunkwmrc

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would one discover the list of third party software they have installed (that might do this)?

Comment: @Harper I show in my answer `launchctl dumpstate | grep '=> true'`. This is one method. Others may be `brew services list`, Activity Monitor, simply `ps -ax`, searching common installation locations (Applications folder, bin folders,  home folder etc.).

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica RE: "Out of curiosity, how would one discover the list of third party software they have installed (that might do this)?" --- The **Software** section of **System Information** is another resource.